# Derivative chain rule clarification

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, chain-rule

In a question, I am trying to find the first degree derivative of a vector

$r(t)= t^2\,\hat\imath - 2\cos\pi\,\hat\jmath$

Is this answer correct ?

answer :  $r'(t) = 2t \,\hat\imath + 0 \,\hat\jmath$

I mean there is no **t** term in j vector,so shouldn't it be 0

Comment: Do you understand the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)?

Comment: $\pi$ is always a constant. The chain rule will show $\frac{d}{dx}sin(\pi x)=\pi\cos(\pi x)$; the only difference is we're using $t$ instead of $x$.

Comment: It looks like @pancini misread $j$ as $t$. You're right that if a vector's $j$-component is constant with respect to $t$, then the vector's derivative with respect to $t$ has zero for its $j$-component.

Comment: @Karl the question was edited, but thanks for clarifying regardless.

Comment: yes I edited the question